# Why is a topological space equal to its interior?

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, proof-explanation

I'm reading *Topology: An Introduction* by Stefan Waldmann.

Proposition 2.3.11 states:

> Let $(M, \mathcal{M})$ be a topological space and let $A, B \subseteq M$ be subsets.
>
> (i) One has... $M^° = M = M^{\text{cl}}$

Can someone explain why this is true? Especially why $M^° = M$.

This seems counterintuitive to me. Say M is the closed unit interval. Is $1 \in [0, 1]$ an interior point?

Is this true because $M \in \mathcal{M}$, so if $p \in M$, there always exists an open set in the neighborhood system of $p$ - namely, $M$?

Comment: This is clearly false, as you’re pointing out, unless there’s something special about the topology. Perhaps you should include more details.

Comment: $M^\circ$ here is the interior of $M$ in the topological space $M$, not in some other ambient space. So yes, $M$ is a perfectly reasonable subset of $M$ that is open in $M$, and $M^\circ$ is by definition the union of all such subsets. (Or, slightly more concisely: the interior of an open subspace $A\subset M$ is $A$ itself, and $M$ is open in $M$.)

Comment: Further to anomaly's comment, as you start to study topology more generally, you need to stay aware that openness and closedness are always relative to some topology. That's why anomaly used the phrase "open _in $M$_".

Comment: By definition, in a topological space $(M,\mathcal{M})$ one has $M\in\mathcal{M}$. In other words, $M$ is an open set by definition, and it is therefore identical to its interior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your idea is exactly right.

Recall that the interior of a subset $A$ of a topological space $M$ is the largest open (in $M$) $U$ contained in $A$. If now $A = M$, then, since by definition $M$ is an open subset of $M$, we have that $M$ is such an open subset of $M$, which makes $M$ the interior of $M$.

The same is of course true for the closure: the closure of a subset $A$ is the smallest closed (in $M$) subset $T$ containing $A$. Again, if $A = M$, then $M$ is closed and contains $M$, and, it is smallest with this property. Hence the closure of $M$ is equal to $M$.

Regarding your example, $1$ is an interior point of the set $[0,1]$ in the topological space $[0,1]$, but it is not an interior point of $[0,1]$ in the topological space $\mathbb{R}$.